# What is "swappable" in model meta for?

Tags: django, django-models, django-users, django-settings

Looking tough django auth models code, I came across this bit of code:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    class Meta(AbstractUser.Meta):
        swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'
```

It's obvious that it has something to do with the new `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting in `settings.py`, but how does it actually work, by what python "trick"?

And in what other situations can it be used?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`swappable` is an "intentionally undocumented" feature which is currently under development / in-test. It's used to handle "I have a base abstract model which has some foreign-key relationships." Slightly more detail is available from [Django's ticketing system](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19103) and [github](https://github.com/wq/django-swappable-models). Because it's a "stealth alpha" feature, it's not guaranteed to work (for anything other than User), and understanding the detailed operation will likely require diving into source code. It works with `AUTH_USER_MODEL` because the `User` model and `swappable` flag were developed together, specifically for each other.

Answer (score 2):

Django 1.5 added the swappable user models, so you can replace Django User model with one of your own (limit the number of characters, use email as identifier...)

More:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/#configurable-user-model
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear in the question. Yes, I guessed what is's for. My question is how does it actually pull that off?