# What are Django swappable models?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

What are swappable models in Django? And Why sometimes when we do a migration a swappable dependency appears in Django migration files?
I have searched for this concept in Django but I did not understand what it really does?! Give me an example of the usage and functionality of this feature in Django.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is "swappable" in model meta for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22025476/what-is-swappable-in-model-meta-for)

Comment: Unfortunately No! I need more detailed answer about this feature on Django.

Comment: Then ask for the specific details you want...

Comment: There is no detail. I just need someone to give me an example of the functionality of swappable models.